# BaseAdapter not populating list

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

So I had a working ArrayAdapter populating my list with a specific item layout but I wanted to incorporate multiple item types so I switched over to a BaseAdpater. My problem is that now the ListView isn't populating the list any more. Any idea what is going on or how to debug it even though it is not causing a crash?

public class SettingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;

private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1 = 0;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2 = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3 = 2;

private static final int OPTION_ID_1 = 0;
private static final int OPTION_ID_2 = 1;
private static final int OPTION_ID_3 = 2;
private static final int OPTION_ID_4 = 3;

private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT = 3;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Setting> options_list;

public SettingAdapter(Context context, List<Setting> options) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    options_list = options;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return options_list.size();
}

@Override
public Setting getItem(int position) {
    return options_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return options_list.get(position).getID();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    SettingHolder holder;

    Setting data = getItem(position);

    if(row == null) {
        inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        holder = new SettingHolder();
        if(data.getType() == OPTION_ID_1){
            Log.d("option1", Integer.toString(OPTION_ID_1));
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_1, parent, false);
            holder.s_heading = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.option1_heading);
            holder.s_sub_heading = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.option1_sub_heading);
        } else if(data.getType() == OPTION_ID_3){
            Log.d("option3", Integer.toString(OPTION_ID_3));
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_2, parent, false);
            holder.s_heading = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.option3_heading);
            holder.s_checked = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.option3_checkbox);
        } else {
            Log.d("option2", Integer.toString(OPTION_ID_2));
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_3, parent, false);
            holder.s_heading = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.option2_heading);
        }
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (SettingHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    if(options_list.size() != 0 && options_list != null){
        Log.d("data", "exists");
        if(data == null){
            holder.s_heading.setText("heading");
            holder.s_sub_heading.setText("sub heading");
            holder.s_checked.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            holder.s_heading.setText(data.getName());
            if(data.getType() == OPTION_ID_1) {
                holder.s_sub_heading.setText(data.getSubHeading());
            }
            if(data.getChecked() != null && data.getType() == OPTION_ID_3){
                holder.s_checked.setChecked(data.getChecked());
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("data", "none");
    }
    return row;
}

class SettingHolder {
    TextView s_heading;
    TextView s_sub_heading;
    CheckBox s_checked;
}
```

}

**And the Activity Class contains:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

    // Grab references to UI elements.
    ListView option_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settings_list);

    setting_db = new SettingDatabaseHandler(this);

    List<Setting> setting_list = setting_db.getAllSettings();

    if(setting_list.size() == 0){
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_1, "Profile Settings"));
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_2, "Font Size", "20sp"));
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_3, "Proxy", "Configure HTTP proxy for network requests"));
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_4, "Offline Mode", false));
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_5, "Location", true));
        setting_db.addSetting(new Setting(OPTION_ID_6, "About", "Help, Terms of Service and Privacy Policy"));
        setting_list = setting_db.getAllSettings();
    }

    if(setting_list != null && setting_list.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("Setting list size::", "" + Integer.toString(setting_list.size()));
    }

    SettingAdapter adapter = new SettingAdapter(this, setting_list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    option_data.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Finally the List layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mapbox.aerove.settings.SettingActivity">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/settings_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ' how to debug it even though it is not causing a crash?' - print to logcat

Answer (score 0):

check the list  is not null and size is  more then zero then call your adapter.

if(setting_list != null && setting_list.size() > 0){

Log.d("List size::",""+setting_list.size() > 0);

SettingAdapter adapter = new SettingAdapter(this, setting_list);
}

in your adapter getView() method

use code

Setting option = options_list.get(position);

instead of

Setting option = data[position];

Answer (score 0):

If your Adapter extends from BaseAdapter, you must override getCount() method, otherwise it will getCount() will always return 0 and your getView() will never get call.

Comment: I merely left that out as it didn't appear to be an issue relevant to this question as they contain basically 1 line of code. Don't worry they are there, if they weren't it wouldn't compile after all as BaseAdapter is Abstract. You also require getItem and getItemId for it to work.

Comment: I would suggest to put all your Adapter code here, because many things seem hidden from us that we are not really sure whether that could be the problem.